# i want to use group call in android

Tags: android, call, conference

Is this possible to call more than one people at the same time . i.e. conference calling.
This should be done by an application not by the default method of conference calling provided by Android.
At the same time can i call more than 1 person?

Answer (score 0):

There is no API supporting this, as far as I know.

Comment: Agreed, there is no way to do this.